# DataGridView cell color not changing on error

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm trying to edit the BackColor of a DataGridViewCell to display as red when the user inputs a value that is incorrect.

```
    private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception is FormatException)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }
```

The color doesn't actually update for reasons I don't understand. It works fine editing ANY other cell just not the selected one.

Comment: I've partially fixed it now by editing the EditingControl's (textbox) back color also. But I still don't understand why the style back color doesn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your code but maybe you need to think again about the logic of the program. It depends from where the exception is coming. If is from a place where the text is not set, there is no way and the color to be changed. DataError is exception so the code after is thrown is not running. I think that DataError doesn't have the info for every exception about that in which cell is the exception. so it's possible that you don't change color because of that.

I don't know your code so I can't help much. But I'll tell you how I would do it.

I'll make a function to check the user inputs and I'll call it in datagridview `CellValidating` event and change color there if the input is not correct

Comment: I seem to have the same problem when updating the color in CellValidating also. Or is that perhaps something to do with the error still being thrown?

Comment: Just to add further - The issue is not that the color property doesn't change. The color property is in fact red, but it doesn't seem to display as red if I want the validation to cancel (remaining in the same textbox).

Comment: Can you try to leave the cell to aply the changes and then focus it again?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to leave the cell if the data was not in the correct format.

Comment: Ahh. I've managed to get the cell to update with this upon validation cancel
    dataGridView1.InvalidateCell(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex])